# Xcode does not support previews in a macOS Widget extension

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, widgetkit

Sorry to bother, but I guess there might be something wrong. I added a Widget Extension in Xcode 14.2 to my macOS applicaiton the way the official document told me to. However, I found it in surprise that the function of previews is not supported? Quite confusing. Is there something wrong with this implementation?

Diagnotics:

```
UnsupportedMacAppExtensionTypeError: Widget extensions are not supported

Xcode does not support previews in a macOS Widget extension

extension: AppExtension(bundleIdentifier: "com.louisstudio.WidgetHub.ProjectWidget", displayName: "ProjectWidgetExtension", kind: PreviewsPlatforms.AppExtension.Kind.homeScreen, signingInformation: Optional(Code Signing {
  identifier: com.louisstudio.WidgetHub.ProjectWidget
  identity: 04FFDADBA91F279D4A0CC823B283DC1115BF09DB
  hasGetTaskAllow: false
  isSandboxed: true
}))
```

I haven't modified anything yet. Everything is exactly what the template of a Widget Extension is like.

```
macOS Version: 12.6.2 (21G320)
Xcode Version: 14.2
```

Hoping to get help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug, please file a feedback via the feedback assistant. In the mean time what you could do is have the contents of the widget which is essentially a view as a separate view that you could preview. And in widget's preview I preview the widget content view.